# Facebook button now showing up

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook like button I want to put on my site, an anyone explain why in the world this is not working?  I don't understand.

```
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=748341751976326";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

> ... snip ...

```
          <p><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://link.to.my.site" data-layout="button_count" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false"></div></p>
```

Comment: Define "not working." Do you get any errors? Give more details, or we can't help you.

Comment: If I view source, it's all there.  No errors in the javsascript console

Answer (score 0):

add the following where you want the button

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/<yourLink>/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: @mikeb actually, the code above has significant differences from the div in your code.

Comment: I tried it, and it showed up one time.  I reloaded the page and it did not work.